# How to save and display values from modal to view by database using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, html, codeigniter

I am fairly new to codeigniter and cant seem to get a hold of this problem, in short i am having problem understanding the flow of data among the CodeIgniter framework. All i want to display is data taken from database using modals and display them in view..

The code in my controller is:

```
$unitData =$this->ClientUnit->getBlockUnits($client_block_ID);
foreach ($unitData->result() as $row){
  for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
    $client_unit_name[$i] = $row->client_unit_name[$i]; 
    $unit_owner_name[$i] = $row->unit_owner_name[$i];     
    }
 }
 $data['client_unit_name'] = $client_unit_name;
 $data['unit_owner_name'] = $unit_owner_name;
 $this->load->view('newblock_unit',$data);
```

My modal file is:

```
function getBlockUnits($client_block_ID) {
  $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM client_units where client_block_ID="'.$client_block_ID.'"');
  return $query; 
}
```

As you can see, from my modal and controller code, the problem is because of multiple rows which are returned, currently i am getting only the last row in all the outputs of view, not individual rows...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are not returning an object or array. In the model you should use, for an object:

```
return $query->result();
```

Or for an array:

```
return $query->result_array();
```

EDIT: You can read everything about this here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: your answer is almost correct but i have got the answer also you redirected me to the answer i was looking for, but as i am new to stackoverflow, i cant answer just yet :p

actually i forgot to mention which row to change in the for loop as mentioned at the bottom of link which you mentioned as according:
$row = $unitData->row($i);

Comment: @blogger if you're not marking mine as correct then just close the thread or do something about this...

Answer (score 0):

you can send the whole array in view and loop it there

```
 $unitData =$this->ClientUnit->getBlockUnits($client_block_ID);


 $data['unitData '] = $unitData->result_array();
 $this->load->view('newblock_unit',$data);
```

in in your view use loop to get the corresponding that

```
 foreach($unitData as $row){
    echo row['client_unit_name'];
     echo row['unit_owner_name'];
 }
```